# Tropo and RapidSMS integration does not work

Tags: python, django, heroku, sms-gateway, tropo

I followed all the steps detailed at http://docs.rapidsms.org/en/develop/tutorial/tutorial04.html to use tropo to send and receive SMS in RapidSMS of Django and deployed it on heroku. Then I tried to do 2 things.

1) send SMS using tropo - I registered a phone number and while selecting the back-end, I was thinking that Tropo (my-tropo-backend) would be an option in the back-end selection. But I don't see tropo as a backend option, just message_tester.

2) receive SMS using tropo - I send a SMS to my tropo phone number, I can see the message coming in tropo log, but I don't see a response from Django URL https://yourhost.example.com/tropo/ in the tropo log (used ping-pong example).

My Django settings for RapidSMS and Tropo is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_BACKENDS = {
    "my-tropo-backend": {
    "ENGINE": "rtropo.outgoing.TropoBackend",
    'config': {
        # Your Tropo application's outbound token for messaging (required)
        'messaging_token': '244e51db5424c3438f122753b8947dee70803dshlfhdfdsdkjfdfd455466565e8e620c05f75323c17864',
        # Your Tropo application's voice/messaging phone number, starting
        # with "+" and the country code (required)
        'number': '+1-000-200-6007',
    },
    },
    "message_tester": {
    "ENGINE": "rapidsms.backends.database.DatabaseBackend",
    },
}
```

urls.py has

```
url(r"^tropo/$",
        views.message_received,
        kwargs={'backend_name': 'my-tropo-backend'},
        name='tropo'),
```

and 'rtropo' has been added to INSTALLED_APPS

What am I missing, Anyone done this before and faced this issue? Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: you are overwriting `ENGINE` in the settings

Comment: Check with Tropo support; they are good about assisting with issues like this. I found that when I was testing SMS on Tropo that for Tropo to send SMS that they have to configure something on their side to make it work. It looks correct in the logs but nothing comes through. You have to request this ability from Tropo support.

Comment: Kevin - I have sent them the log file. waiting for their response. Should I be able to see 'Tropo' as 'my-tropo-backend' in the back-end dropdown, where we add a Contact in RapidSMS. Currently, I just see 'message_test'

Comment: There is something wrong with my tropo RapidSMS integration, it is not showing JSON on the URL. It's just blank with no error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was not putting the trailing slash at the end of the URL in Tropo settings. Example: 
I was giving https://yourhost.example.com/tropo it should be https://yourhost.example.com/tropo/

With the trailing slash at the end, Django redirects to the same URL after adding a trailing slashes and this this time the data is sent by GET and not by POST.